# iPhone 4s in Xcode 9.1 with iOS 9 as deployment target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm working on a new project having **iOS 9** as **deployment target** in **`Xcode` 9.1**. In the simulator I have the **`iPhone 4s`** but its **`iOS`** version is not displayed. I searched about the support of **`iOS 9`** in this **`iPhone`** and I found some answers saying that the iPhone 4s is supporting the iOS 9 and others saying the opposite so I'm confused. At this date, is **`iOS 9`** supported on **`iPhone 4s`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, iOS 9 is supported on iPhone 4S. but iOS 10 is not supported. Last supported is iOS 9.3.5

You can see the Simulator and iOS in XCode, Window > Devices and Simulator or Cmd+Shift+2.

In the Simulator Tab, you can see the list of simulators. Normally by defaults, iPhone 4S Simulator is installed with iOS 8.1.

If you need to see more iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3 e.g. you can press the '+' on the left below to add more simulators. And check on the 'Show as run destination' to run the app on this simulator in XCode.

If you do not have iOS 9.3 simulator, you can choose the option to download more simulator or do it from XCode > Preferences > Components

[image]

Comment: What did you mean by "but iOS is not supported."?

Comment: iOS 10, 10 was skipped :(

Comment: Will iOS 9 be supported on iPhone 4S in the future?

Comment: iPhone 4s we can use ios10.3 version also? @Llg your deployment target is ios9 it will work on iPhone 4s also, but xcode9 officially will not provide simulator support for  iPhone 4s.

Comment: Can you please see the second answer of this SO and tell me you opinion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640715/how-to-set-up-xcode-9-for-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s-development

Comment: Apple support and is it possible to install are two different terms. Apple dont support older phone and iOS. But you can build your app targetting them. Even you can type 7.0 in place of deployment target and the app will work in those devices.

Comment: So to conclude: iPhone 4s supports iOS 9. Thank you @karim !